# Creating an N-Amount of Forms using WTForms

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm new to flask and WTForms so sorry in advance.

Anyways, I'm trying to create multiple forms using the same form defined below in `forms.py`

```
File_Choices = [('1', 'ex1.pdf'), ('2', 'ex2.pdf')
class Inputs(Form):
    Files = SelectField(u'File', choices=File_Choices,validators =[Required()])
```

I am familiar with the fact  that I have to declare something along the lines of: `form1=Inputs()` to declare a form in the `views.py`, however the problem arises when I need to declare an unknown amount of forms and track the selected values.

My specific problem is that I have a list that contains N elements and each element has to correspond to a file that the user selects from the form. So I've broken down my problem to just creating N number of forms first and thought about using a for loop like this:

```
for i in range(len(PDF_list))
    form'i'=Input()
```

So the end product if the length of the list is 5, is 5 Input forms declared as form1, form2, form3, form4, form5. I know this obviously doesn’t work the way I just coded it but that's the functionality I'm trying to get so I can still access the submitted values using something like

`dict(File_Choices).get(form'i'.Files.data)`.

Theres probably a really obvious way to do this however, I'm new to using flask and WTForms so any help is appreciated and in your solution if you could explain step by step what you're doing since I'm new, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is [FieldList](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList).

So you'd have something like:

```
from wtforms.fields import FieldList

file_choices = [('1', 'ex1.pdf'), ('2', 'ex2.pdf')
class Inputs(Form):
    files = FieldList(
        SelectField(u'File', choices=file_choices, validators =[Required()]),
        min_entries = N
    )
```

`min_entries` specifies how many "SelectFields" should be present on the form. This way you have one form with multiple dropdown select fields each having the same list of file_choices.

In your template file, you could output all the select fields like this (this will display all N selectfields:

```
<html>
    <form action="" method=post>
        {{ form.files }}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</html>
```

You could also iterate over `form.files` and style each `SelectField` individually

Now when your form is posted, you can access each `SelectField` by iterating over `form.files` like so:

```
for select_field in form.files:
    print(select_field.data)
```

You can also access `SelectField` using an index. To access the third `SelectField`:

```
form.files[2].data
```

will return '1' or '2' depending on which file the user selected in that `SelectField`

Comment: I see that is functionality I was looking for,however I'm still slightly confused on how I access the selected field from the user. I have tried looking at the documentation but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: See update to my answer. FieldLists are essentially lists of Fields so you can access the fields the hold like other python lists: direct indexing, iterators, length. In this case each item in the list is a SelectField.